# Error3 The "CompileXaml" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working with Xamarin and I have a error when I want to compile it.
This is the folowing

Error   3   The "CompileXaml" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'XamlServicesWP, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'XamlServicesWP, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.CompileXaml.GenerateCode(ITaskItem item, Boolean isApplication)
   at Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.CompileXaml.Execute()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__20.MoveNext()

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
    Hello.WinPhone

Since I have tried (for example I installed the Windows Phone 8.1 and 8.0 SDK and Windows Phone 8.1 emulator Update 3) some similar error added
in this forum and I could not fix it, maybe someone could help me. would it be possible?
Thanks in advance
Alejandro

Comment: Sorry again but I forgot to say that I have installed Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Update 4. thanks and sorry for my little english

Comment: You need to search for "fusion logging".  This will show you were the CLR is searching for the assembly that's missing.  Once you know where it should be, you have to figure out why it's not there.  Where is that assembly currently on your system?  Why isn't it installed correctly?  Who owns the assembly?  Ask them where it should be located, and why it isn't there.